# TS - Local path of image

Tags: typescript

I would like to store the local path of an uploaded image in a variable. I created a `FileReader` in order to get information on the file. Here is my code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
console.log(event.target.files[0]);
```

This is an example output:

```
lastModified: 1536526410000
lastModifiedDate: Sun Sep 09 2018 16:53:30 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00) {}
name: "slider-2.jpg"
size: 627442
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

I would like to get the local path of the computer, since this is angular, when I tried `window.location.pathname` but it just returns the path from localhost being `localhost:4200/register`

How can I get my full path?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)